# Orthogonal transformations in 3 Dimensions

Tags: vectors

I'll cite what my lecture notes say because my lecturer didn't explain an aspect of it, and I need to understand it:

Orthogonal transformations in 3 Dimensions:

"Consider two right-handed Cartesian coordinate systems with a common origin, ($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$$)$ and ($x$'$_1$$, $$x$'$_2$, $x'$$_3$). Denote the respective unit vectors by (**e**$_1$,
**e**$_2$, **e**$_3$$)$ and (**e**$'$$_1$$, $**e**$'$$_2$$, $**e**$'$$_3$). We introduce the matrix $L_{ij}$ $:=$ **e**$'$$_i$ $\bullet$ **e**$_j$. As both the primed and unprimed basis vectors are constant vectors, $L$ does not depend on the position. We now show that $L$ completely characterises the transformation between the two systems.

Recall that each set of basis vectors is orthonormal, **e**$_i$ $\bullet$ **e**$_j$ $=$ $\delta_{ij}$ and **e**$'$$_i$ $\bullet$ **e**$'$$_j$ $=$ $\delta_{ij}$. We can therefore expand **e**$'$$_i$ in the unprimed basis as **e**$'$$_i$ $=$ (**e**$'$$_i$ $\bullet$ **e**$_j$)**e**$_j$ , and we can similarly expand **e**$_i$ in the primed basis as **e**$_i$ $=$ (**e**$_i$ $\bullet$ **e**$'$$_j$)**e**$'$$_j$ $=$ (**e**$'$$_j$ $\bullet$ **e**$_i$)**e**$'$$_j$, where the last step uses the symmetry of the dot product. In terms of $L$ , these relations read

**e**$'$$_i$ $=$ $L_{ij}$**e**$_j$   , **e**$_i$ $=$ $L_{ji}$**e**$'$$_j$ .

The matrix $L_{ij}$ arising as the dot product of the "new" basis vectors with the "old" ones is an orthogonal matrix. Indeed, since both sets of basis vectors are orthonormal we have

$\delta_{ij}$ $=$ **e**$'$$_i$ $\bullet$ **e**$'$$_j$ $=$ ($L_{ik}$**e**$_k$) $\bullet$ ($L_{jl}$**e**$_l$) $=$ $L_{ik}$$L_{jl}$**e**$_k$ $\bullet$ **e**$_l$ $=$ $L_{ik}$$L_{jl}$$\delta_{kl}$ $=$ $L_{ik}$$L_{jk}$ which is the orthogonality property for the matrix $L$.

Let us also work out the consequence of the assumption that a right-handed coordinate system is mapped into a right-handed one. We have

$\epsilon_{ijk}$ $=$ **e**$'$$_i$ $\bullet$ **e**$'$$_j$ x **e**$'$$_k$ $=$ $L_{il}$$L_{jm}$$L_{kn}$**e**$_l$ $\bullet$ **e**$_m$ x **e**$_n$ $=$ $L_{il}$$L_{jm}$$L_{kn}$$\epsilon_{lmn}$ $=$ $det$$L$$\epsilon_{ijk}$

Hence $det$$L$ $=$ 1 , and $L$ is $special$ $orthogonal$ "

The bit I don't understand is why does $L_{il}$$L_{jm}$$L_{kn}$ $=$ $det$$L$ ?

Comment: Why not? And yes I know I'm just copying my lecturer's use of Index notation

Comment: Sorry I think I may have amended the issue.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I see the issue. I've written it down wrong, now is it solved?

Comment: Looks fine now. The question is then why $(\det L)\epsilon_{ijk}=L_{il}L_{jm}L_{kn}\epsilon_{lmn}$.

Comment: Yes it is, that is the question